# Apply template to a specific page

Tags: 7, theming

I have a requirement to apply template to a specific page and not to the pages following the same url pattern.
For example I have a page with the path /asia. I also have pages with the paths /asia/india, /asia/china etc. I would like to create a template which applies only for /asia and not for other paths. I created the template file page--asia.tpl.php but it is getting applied for /asia/india and /asia/china as well. Is there a way to specifically map the template to this specific path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite Drupal defalut suggestion, You can make your own suggestion for template.

In your case you have defined a menu called asia for that specific template is required, to implement this use this code

```
 **
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  if(isset($variables['asia']) && arg(1) == '')
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__asiapage';
}
```

create a tpl file in theme called page--asiapage.tpl.php, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! This worked.I used the condition `if(arg(0)=='asia' && arg(1)=='')` instead of the one specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below points:

1. Create a file with the name "page--node--nodeid.tpl.php" template.
2. Replace nodeid with the node you want to theme.
3. Clear the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Astha! This solution doesn't work in my case since the page is an empty pagecallback and not a node.